# pause button not clickable in music player

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton

I am a newbie in android development.In my music player app, whenever I click the play/pause button to pause the song , nothing happens. It seems like the imagebutton is not clickable because nothing happens on touching it. I am not able to pause the song playing. I have tried all possible solutions mentioned on stack overflow still its not working.Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

**XML File :**

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2.40"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_previous" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlay1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:paddingLeft="230dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_next" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

**btn_play.xml :**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download4"
        android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/az"
        android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

**PlayListActivity.java :**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_list);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mMusicList = getAudioList();

   ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                try {
                    playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getAudioList() {
        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}, null, null,
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();

        String[] songs = new String[count];
        mAudioPath = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                i++;
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        mCursor.close();

        return songs;
    }


    private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_building_music_player);
        Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
//mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        acv(path);
        abc();
    }

    public void acv(String path) {
        getInit();

        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(path);
        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
            album.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            artist.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            album.setText("Unknown Album");
            artist.setText("Unknown Artist");
        }

    }

    public void getInit() {
        album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverart1);
        album = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Album);
        artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    }


    public  void abc(){
        ImageButton btnPlay1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay1);
        btnPlay1.setOnClickListener(
                new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mMediaPlayer.pause();
                        } else {
                            mMediaPlayer.start();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Adapter doesnt seen to be in the same LayoutXML, maybe your findViewById(R.id.btnPlay1) are returning null.

Comment: that seems right , thanks ..can you help me fix that ?

Comment: You need to get the button from where you inflated it

Answer (score 0):

Your listener change it to this :

```
btnPlay1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(Act.this, "test click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: its still not working, no text is displayed, seems the button is not clickable !!

Comment: you button is in list view ?

Comment: no , it isn't ...its in a different layout than listview and maybe that is the causing problem but it has to be in a different layout